# React native Expo Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code

Tags: android, react-native, expo

After updating my app I am trying to upload my expo app to the playstore but getting error again and again. I changed the version in app.json **version": "2.0.0"** and also try this **version": "1.0.1"** and **version": "1.0.2"**. I have no idea why it is showing me this error.

**Answer**
The ios.buildNumber and android.versionCode distinguish different binaries of your app. Make sure to increment these for each build you upload to the App Store or Google Play Store.

Comment: see this doc for information on "versionCode" https://docs.expo.dev/classic/building-standalone-apps/#2-configure-appjson

Answer (score 23):

You need to increase the android versionCode and iOS buildNumber, not the version string.

```
"ios": {
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
  "buildNumber": "1.0.0" //increase it for iOS
},
"android": {
  "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
  "versionCode": 1 //increase it for android
}
```

Comment: After 3 days finally I've got the solution, thanks so much

Comment: Thankyou for this @anthony I have been trawling the internet all day for this

Comment: i got the error: "build.production.android.versionCode" is not allowed

Answer (score 13):

There is an automated way to do this where expo does it for you. It prevents wasting time & resources of rebuilding again when you forget to update those versions.

In the `eas.json` the `"autoIncrement": true` does the trick!

```
{
  "cli": {
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "staging": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "autoIncrement": true
    }
  }
}
```

here is more on the docs with another option for `local` instead of `remote`: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/app-versions/

Comment: Worth noting that autoIncrement isn't available if you are using `app.config.js` in lieu of `app.json`